# How to use both older version and latest version of jquery in a website along with third party plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an application where the jquery library(currently refrenced ver is 1.4.4) was never updated  and the application is very big with lot of usage of jquery spread accross different pages.

I cannot upgrade the jquery library to latest version as this will break the entire website.

Now I have a problem to use third party plugins like datatable, bootstrap js,  etc.

I know we can use jquery.noConflict() and give an alias to the latest jquery library and start using that.

But I am not sure if the third party plugins will also work as I think they all are using *$* in their code and if I use the above solution my $ will be pointing to older version of the jquery file.

Please help me with your suggestions in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you want, but it will be a lot easier in the long run to change your codebase to only use a single, up to date version of jQuery. Otherwise you'll have multiple libraries to maintain and ensure that they're not in conflict and it will quickly become a nightmare

Comment: It's highly unlikely any of the [respectable] third party libraries are using `$` directly.  They will be using `$` by passing in `jQuery` in the standard way: `(function( $ ) { /* plugin using $ */ })(jQuery);`.  But, yes, `jQuery` would be pointing to the one defined *at the time the plugin runs*.

Comment: Have a look at jquery migrate:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Comment: If you're using an older version of jquery, then it stands to reason you'd need to use older versions of the plugins - so find older versions that match the jquery version.   If they're aren't any, then you need to make the call to upgrade (using jquery migrate) or not use that plugin.

Comment: Older plugins we are using and I am in dire need to use Bootstrap.js features but this doesn't support the jQuery version we are using i.e 1.4.4 and I am helpless here as I cannot upgrade the jQuery also. So looking for some kind of a workaround.